# Concatenating text and preserving conditional formatting as static

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with two rows that have conditional formating in them (rules like if lower than then colour text). I need to concatenate those two rows and preserve formatting from each row separately. Due to this I can't just concatenate values and paste formats as it will apply conditional formatting to the whole text and not just the parts of it.

I have searched for solution and found that you can convert conditional formatting to static formatting by using Range.DisplayFormat property. In my code I am basically going by each character 
and copying DisplayFormat from source cell (with conditional formatting) and using the same font, size, bold and color on characters in my target range.

The result should look like this:

[image: desired result]

Unfortunately, I am getting just a concatenated string without formatting. Do you know a better way to achieve what I need? Or could you help me with fixing the existing code.

```
Sub Merge_Cells()
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngFrom1 As Range
Dim rngFrom2 As Range
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim lenFrom1 As Integer
Dim lenFrom2 As Integer

  Set rngFrom1 = Cells(59, 1) 'first row
  Set rngFrom2 = Cells(60, 1) 'second row
  Set rngTo = Cells(64, 1)
  lenFrom1 = Len(rngFrom1)
  lenFrom2 = Len(rngFrom2)

  rngTo.Value = rngFrom1.Text & " " & rngFrom2.Text 'concatenating text

  For i = 1 To lenFrom1
    With rngTo.Characters(i, 1).Font
      .Name = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle
      .Bold = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
      .Size = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
      .ColorIndex = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex
    End With
  Next i

  For i = 1 To lenFrom2
    'start from character that is after space
    With rngTo.Characters(lenFrom1 + 1 + i, 1).Font 
      .Name = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Name
      .Bold = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
      .Size = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
      .ColorIndex = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex
    End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to apply conditional formatting to "half" of the string?

Comment: Partial format of concatenated cells is not supported: See [partial format contents in a concatendated cell](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_archive/partial-format-contents-in-a-concatendated-cell/e5009136-dd7f-4899-97e6-7e6e3500ae51)

Comment: I have conditional formatting for values in Total Value and Delta rows. I want to concatenate values from those two rows while preserving formatting from each of them. From my understanding this can't be done with conditional formatting, so I want to convert from it to the static formatting for each "half" of the string. This is why I'm using trying to colour each character. It works if the source formatting is static and not conditional.

Comment: How have you made the picture in the question? With Paint? Or is it a screenshot from Excel?

Comment: Screenshot from Excel. It is a desired result that was achieved by manually colouring parts of text and giving them appropriate fonts (Wingdings for arrow).

Comment: Easiest way would be just to use 2 consecutive cells E.g. A1 for total value and B1 for delta. Borderline around both cells, and it looks like the same. This saves you much time and I see no disadvantages.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I was thinking about that solution but the length of strings will vary day-to-day and there are more than 10 columns for which I'll be applying solutions. That will require quite a lot of manual adjusting daily which I'd rather avoid. :)

Comment: @Seidhe just format A to the right and B to the left. That way it looks almost the same. As you can read in my link above partial format of concatenated cells is not supported in Excel. You might have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895205/bold-text-in-a-concatenate-formula/49895502#49895502 which is a similar question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I can't use your solution (neither the one with two cells close to each other nor the one you linked). I will probably try with copying and pasting my source range to Word and then pasting it back to Excel as this way you can preserve formatting without having rules  and then I'll use my part of macro (as it works with normal - not conditional formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I have partly achieved what I wanted by copying my source range with all the conditional formatting to Word and pasting it back to Excel to another range. This way the formatting was preserved but there were no rules for conditional formatting and all the font parameters were readable by my macro. Only problem is when using non-standard colours as they are different in Excel and Word (for example red turns to pink)

```
Sub Merge_Cells()
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngFrom1 As Range
Dim rngFrom2 As Range
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim lenFrom1 As Integer
Dim lenFrom2 As Integer
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim rngcopy As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("test")
ws.Visible = True
ws.Activate    
Set rngcopy = Range("C51", "C53")
rngcopy.Select
' Copy Excel Selection
Selection.Copy

' Create new Word Application
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False

' Create new Word Document
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

' Paste Excel range into Word document
objWord.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True

' Copy text from cells
If objDoc.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
    objDoc.Tables(1).Select
    objWord.Selection.Copy
End If

' Close Microsoft Word and not save changes
objWord.Quit False
Set objWord = Nothing
'Paste it back to Excel
ws.Range("C58").Activate
ws.Paste

'Old code
Set rngFrom1 = Cells(59, 3) 'first row
Set rngFrom2 = Cells(60, 3) 'second row
Set rngTo = Cells(64, 3)
lenFrom1 = Len(rngFrom1)
lenFrom2 = Len(rngFrom2)
rngTo.Value = rngFrom1.Text & " " & rngFrom2.Text 'concatenating text

For i = 1 To lenFrom1
    With rngTo.Characters(i, 1).Font
      .Name = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle
      .Bold = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
      .Size = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
      .ColorIndex = rngFrom1.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex
    End With
Next i

For i = 1 To lenFrom2
    'start from character that is after space
    With rngTo.Characters(lenFrom1 + 1 + i, 1).Font 
      .Name = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Name
      .Bold = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
      .Size = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
      .ColorIndex = rngFrom2.DisplayFormat.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```